# Prepared statements connection error

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am trying to use a Prepared Statement to insert a record (into an embedded java database). I want the information to enter when I click the save button (JButton). I am new to Java and have never tried to use a prepared statement.

I am having problems getting my connection (con) to know it is a connection. The following code is for the prepared statement which I am placing in the action listener.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thank you so much for your time. I hope I did the code correctly.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Users (UserId, fName, lastName, userName, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

stmt.setString(2, "fName" );
stmt.setString(3, "lastName" );
stmt.setString(4, "userName" );
stmt.setString(5, "password" );
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: How are you creating 'con'?

Comment: Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);

Comment: host, uName, and uPass are variables that are also givin

Comment: ..and what is the actual problem? Any errors?

Comment: con.prepareStatement... con is underlined and says it cannot find the variable

Comment: Sounds like a a scoping issue then. We need more code :)

Comment: Some drivers require to be registered to the DriverManager in order to be seen by the JDBC connection string. Do you have some Class.forName("classofthejdbcdriver") somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the prepared statement.  It is more basic than that.

> con.prepareStatement... con is underlined and says it cannot find the variable

That means that `con` is not in scope.  We don't know what you've actually done, but here's an example:

```
if (foo) {
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
}
String sql = "INSERT INTO Users (UserId, fName, lastName, userName, password) " +
             "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

// Compilation error     vvv
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql, 
                                              Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

The problem is that `con` is a local variable, and it goes out of scope at the end of the block in which it is declared.  If you try to use a variable that is out of scope, the compiler will say that it cannot find it.  Essentially, it doesn't know what variable you are talking about ....

Answer (score 4):

This snippet:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
```

would indicate that the `Connection` `con` is only being defined locally. Make this a class member variable and use:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
```

---

You don't appear to be setting the first parameter in your `PreparedStatement`:

```
stmt.setString(1, UserId);
```

Also are you sure you want to set literal values for the parameters?

**Update:**

As the first parameter is auto-generated, you will probably want:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Users (fName, lastName, userName, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

PreparedStatement stmt = ...   
stmt.setString(1, fName);
stmt.setString(2, lastName);
stmt.setString(3, userName);
stmt.setString(4, password);
```

Comment: I am not sure how to add the first parameter as it is autogenerated

Comment: The question was about the connection but your observation and answer regarding the parameters is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

For Creating Connection object to connect with Database.Try out like this...

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_host, DB_UserName, DB_UserPassword);
```

It will create local object con for Connection class.

From your statment i understand you are using **UserId** as autoincrement field. you no need to enter value explicitly.

So you modify ur statement as

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Users (fName, lastName, userName, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
stmt.setString(1, "fName" );
stmt.setString(2, "lastName" );
stmt.setString(3, "userName" );
stmt.setString(4, "password" );
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Try it out. Hope it ll works for you.